# Store IDT register returns Stack Smashing

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, inline

I wrote the following C program to view the contents of the IDT register:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short IDTLimit;    // 2 bytes
    unsigned short LowIDTBase;  // 2 bytes
    unsigned short HighIDTBase; // 2 bytes

} idt_info_t; // 6 bytes total

int main(void)
{
        idt_info_t idt_info;

        __asm__ __volatile__ ("sidt %[idtptr]" : [idtptr]"=m"(idt_info));

        printf("IDT Limit    : 0x%02X\n", idt_info.IDTLimit);
        printf("Low IDT Base : 0x%02X\n", idt_info.LowIDTBase);
        printf("High IDT Base: 0x%02X\n", idt_info.HighIDTBase);

        return 0;
}
```

So when I run it it returns:

```
IDT Limit    : 0xFFF
Low IDT Base : 0x00
High IDT Base: 0x00
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Instead I wrote the following program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        unsigned char buffer[10];
        unsigned char i;

        __asm__ __volatile__ ("sidt %[idtptr]" : [idtptr]"=m"(buffer));

        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                printf("0x%02X ", buffer[i]);

        return 0;
}
```

And I don't get the "Stack Smashing" error I get this:

```
0xFF 0x0F 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFE 0xFF 0xFF
```

The size of the IDT register is 6 bytes which matches the size of the idt_info structure which it shouldn't produce any error, but in the second program the size of buffer is 10 bytes and it runs fine.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you compiling for 64 bit?  In 64 bit mode, the IDT structure is 10 bytes long.

Comment: I checked the executable file with "readelf -h" and it shows its 64bit, also I checked the size of idt_info with a printf("%ld", sizeof(idt_info)) and it says its 6 bytes.

Comment: Yes, and `sidt` requires a 10 byte buffer in 64 bit mode.  Refer to the instruction set reference for details.

Comment: Thanks now I know why it needed 10 bytes to work.